# Writing custom validator in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm trying to write a custom validator that will check for the number of words entered into a text field.

I was trying to follow the example in railscasts episode 211 - http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3

So I made a file /lib/word_limit_validator.rb and copied in the same code from the tutorial. I know that this code doesn't count the number of words, I am just trying to use it because I know how it is supposed to behave.

```
class WordLimitValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator  
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)  
    unless value =~ /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i  
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not formatted properly")  
    end  
  end  
end
```

Here's the line I used in my validation:

```
  validates :body, :presence => true,
                   :word_limit => true
```

When I tried to load the form I got the following error:

> Unknown validator: 'word_limit'

How do I get rails to recognize my validator?

System spec:
Mac OS 10.6.7
Rails 3.0.4
ruby 1.9.2p136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in lib/ aren't autoloaded anymore in Rails.  So, you have a few options.

- You can add lib to your autoload paths in your application.rb:
  `config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib )`
- You can include by adding file with something like this to config/initializers: 
  `require File.join( Rails.root, 'lib', 'word_limit_validator')`
- If you only need it one place, you can just put it in the same file as your model.

Comment: Yeah, I should've said -- the second option is IMO the best option.  Not sure what the Rails 3 'best practice' is.

Answer (score 10):

You could also create an *app/validators* directory in your rails project and put your custom validators there. This way they will automatically be loaded.

Comment: It works but... when I change something in `app/validators/*.rb` Rails (or Spork) doesnt reload code. A quick workaround is to add another `watch` line to `Guardfile`.