# Getting custom validators to work with the client_side_validations gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, client-side

I've written a custom validator and am looking for ways to get it work with the client_side_validations gem. Right now it still allows me to submit my form and then I get a the error box and error messages. I was wondering if there is a way to modify the gem or how I need to format validation.

Here's the last question I asked about how to setup my validation: [Writing custom validator in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024439/writing-custom-validator-in-rails-3)

Is the best way to do this to express the maximum word count in terms of a regular expression?

Comment: I'm going to use this regular expression. /^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){1,100}$/ 

It accomplishes the same goal. I am still interested in how to make custom validators work with client_side_validations though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki has pretty detailed information on how to write custom validators: https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/wiki/Custom-Validators

You need to follow the guide on the wiki for how to write the Rails validator in such a way that it works with the ClientSideValidations gem. For example, if I took the validator on your other post I would write it like this:

```
class WordLimitValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i
      object.errors.add(attribute, :word_limit, options.merge(:value => value))
    end
  end
end
```

You'll then need to add the error message for :word_limit to your en.yml file:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      word_limit: "is not formatted properly"
```

Finally you'll need to add the validator for the Javascript. I usually create a new file called rails.validations.custom.js It's the convention I've been using as I don't want to mess around with the core file.

```
// rails.validations.custom.js
clientSideValidations.validators.local['word_limit'] = function(element, option) {
  if (!/^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){1,100}$/.test(element.val())) {
    return options.message;
  }
});
```

And that should do it. If you're copy/pasting I may have made some syntax errors as I'm doing this off the top of my head.

To be honest though, why not just use the Rails format validator? You could do this in your model:

```
validates :body, :format => { :with => /^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){1,100}$/, :message => "is not formatted properly" }
```

And that effectively gets you the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing, the Regular Expression you have may or may not work in Javascript. Javascript and Ruby have different Regular Expression engines and while most things work in both not all things do. So you may have to test the expression in javascript to see if you're getting the results you want. If not then you'll need to the have a different Regex in the javascript validator.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll be sure to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've just added the said functionality. If you point your Gemfile to the master branch on Github you should be able to conditionally force validators in the manner I described.